# Sort does not work on Text query with parse-server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

The parse-server documentation is a bit outdated: http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/

Try this query:

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"name":{"$text":{"$search":{"$term":"Milk"}}}}' \
  --data-urlencode 'order="$score"' \
  --data-urlencode 'key="$score"' \
  https://localhost:1337/parse/classes/Groceries
```

And it with return this error:

```
{
"code": 102,
"error": "Invalid parameter for query: key"
}
```

Question, how do you sort by "score" when doing Full-text search with Parse if the query parameters does not work?

Comment: You seem to be following the example from http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#queries-on-string-values, where notably this is the **Postgres** example and not the **MongoDB** one. MongoDB uses a special `$meta` value to enable sort, which I'm not sure is supported in the Parse Server REST API. Also the specific error is on `key` in your statement, which is not a valid option for a MongoDB back end. MongoDB always uses `_id` as the key, and you don't specify it in requests.

Comment: What is the correct format to sort text query with Parse on mongodb?

Comment: As stated [Sorting With Text Score in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#return-the-text-search-score) requires special options issued to both the result project and sort key "as an object". That object format does not at a glance appear to be supported by the parse REST API. If you want a "MongoDB text sort", then you *may* need to actually use the native API directly instead.

Comment: Grepping through the actual code, there seem to be [two places](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=textScore&type=) where `textScore` with `$meta` is substituted for `$score`. So it would appear to be supported, but as per the error message here, the code suggests that should be `keys` instead of `key`, as in `--data-urlencode 'keys="$score"'`. So it appears to be a typo in the documentation.

Comment: It worked, if you can make your comment and answer I will be glad to accept it as the correct answer for this SO question. Thanks!