# Is it possible to run native MongoDB queries from within Parse Cloud Code?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

Since it seems that the ParseServer does not support MongoDB score sorting to effectively achieve this kind of query:

```
db.getCollection('Store').find(
   { $text: { $search: "gaming mouse" } }, { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort( { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } )
```

...because the ParseServer throws error when you try to sort a text query (it seems it is only implemented for Postgres backend, not MongoDB.

What can be done in a Parse Cloud Code to have text search sorting? Is it possible to run native MongoDB queries from within Parse Cloud Code?

Comment: That's `.sort()` and not `,sort()` with the "comma" you have there. And it would seem your "real question" is actually *"How can I run this with the Parse REST API?"*, which is actually [what you are already asking in this other question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826408/sort-does-not-work-on-text-query-with-parse-server). Do you really need to ask the same question twice?

Comment: No it's not possible, parse server doesn't use aggregation, it uses simple mongodb queries like find, sort, update to query the data in mongodb, this is the biggest demerit since it makes the API very slow and also this the reason we remove this parse middleware and use the core MEAN stack to develop application. Hope it helps

Comment: @NeilLunn I think this is a totally different question compared to my other post.

Comment: I don't see how it's any different, since it's not like you can send this query in any other way than through the REST API. Perhaps you should be paying more attention to what is said on the other post.

Comment: @NeilLunn I think I will just delete this question